# Does Javascript use the local computer time?

Tags: javascript, time

This may be a dumb question, I'm 99% sure it does, but I need to be sure... does JS use the local computer's time?

Comment: What other time would it use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it does use the computer's local time. To test, change your computer time and it will reflect in `new Date`

Answer (score 2):

It'll use the time on whatever computer is running the code.

In most cases, that's in a web browser on a client computer, so it'll use whatever time the web browser sees.  This is most likely the computer's local time (unless the browser is doing something weird, which most don't and I've never seen).

Note that if you're using something like node.js and running server-side Javascript then it'll use the local time for *that* computer instead :)

Comment: Just curious. What are those weird things?

Comment: @JavaGeek: What weird things?  Weird things that a browser might be doing?  Could be anything.  There are tons of browsers out there and some of them could be doing something strange, maybe specific-purpose browsers or something.  Just commenting on how browser behavior is never 100% guaranteed when dealing with web development.

Answer (score 0):

JS is client-side script language and as all client-side languages it can't get server time. The only way to get server time is sending request to server via AJAX (or any ActivX based tecnology).