# Javascript Date.ToLocaleTimeString() doesn't match computer's time format

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, datetime

My computer is defined to use 24h format:

[image]

However, when I use `var date = new Date("10/25/2020 19:32")`
and then `date.toLocaleTimeString()`

I get a 12h format:
[image]

Comment: The use of "locale" in "toLocaleString" is a misnomer. It actually uses a language code, derived from either OS or browser settings, to determine the format to use. It doesn't use any other host setting for formatting. However, additional options can be included when calling [*toLocaleString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) that further affect the format in ways that can really only be discovered by trial and error.

Answer (score 2):

When no options are provided, the output of [*toLocaleString*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.prototype.tolocalestring) is entirely implementation dependent so may or may not use host settings, however they are almost certain to treat it as equivalent to a language of "default" with no options, i.e.

```
new Date().toLocaleString('default') === new Date().toLocaleString()
```

which returns true in every browser I tested. The important part is:

> [toLocaleString is] intended to represent the Date in the current time zone in a convenient, human-readable form that corresponds to the conventions of the host environment's current locale.

Note that it should use the conventions of the locale (i.e. place or region), not the host system.

When a language and/or options are provided, the output is governed by ECMA-402 and is primarily based on the language code provided as the first argument (misnamed "locale"). Options also affect the output, however the host settings are not used other than to obtain the language code to use in the case of "default" for the first argument.

The underlying principle of the *toLocale* methods is that appropriate formatting can be determined from a language and other fairly vague options. Implementation developers then work out what format to use for each language and option combination. Clearly the host system settings can't be used when language or options are provided as that defeats the entire purpose of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that the browser will use the settings in the operating system is probably wrong.

You [leave it to the browser to choose a locale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) for you.

My guess is that it is based on `window.navigator.languages`. This could be *"en-US"* in your case, hence the 12h format.

Comment: Your answer conflicts with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234536/does-javascript-use-the-local-computer-time but I guess the toLocaleTimeString is implemented with language settings while new Date uses computer's format. Basically what I'm trying to achieve is a way to always format the datetime with the computer's settings. is there any to do that?

Comment: There are two aspects to this: Time & Format. Yes, the browser uses the computer's local time, but apparently not its local format. I've looked around for you, and your question has been asked before, here in SO, but there's no answer that shows us how the local format can be obtained from the OS.

Comment: Yep.. That's why I posted this question :)

Comment: My best guess is that it cannot be done, but proving a negative is difficult.