# Does toLocaleString use the users timezone or the computer that hosts the code?

Tags: javascript, timezone, locale, utc

I need to convert a timestamp into human readable format. I'd like the resulting human readable format to be the users location (not the computer I deployed my code to).

I currently have this:

```
let d = 1662835646;
new Date(d * 1000).toLocaleString()
```

Which gives me this:

```
9/10/2022, 2:47:26 PM
```

Which is correct for my timezone (EST) but I don't have a way to test this for other timezones.

Basically all I'm asking is, will the above code work to where a user could be anywhere else in the world and it will show the correct date relevant to THEIR location.

Comment: Related question: [Date.ToLocaleTimeString() doesn't match computer's time format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64521561/943435)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically all I'm asking is, will the above code work to where a user could be anywhere else in the world and it will show the correct date relevant to THEIR location.

Yes, by default, the default locale and time zone are that of where the code is *executing* - not where it is hosted.  This is true at least for browser-based JavaScript, that means  it will be that of the user.  For server-based JavaScript (Node.js, etc.), it will be that of the *server*, because that's what's executing the code.

> ...  I don't have a way to test this for other timezones.

Yes you do. You can change your computer's time zone and locale (language) settings and restart your browser.

Alternatively, if you're using a Chromium based browser like Google Chrome or Microsoft Edge, you can [change the location](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/geolocation/) in the Sensors area in the dev tools.  Each location can be customized for locale and time zone.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Function toLocaleString can take two params: locales & options

You can set locale to a certain locale and with the options parameter, you can set timezone and many other options to format the date.

Check the following link to see all the options available

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#options](https://Intl.DateTimeFormat()%20constructor)